# Converting list to array and back

Tags: java, time-complexity

If you want to convert a list to and array or an array to a list, are these operations done in constant or linear time? (for example using the methods: Arrays.asList(), toArray() )

Comment: have you checked the library code? see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this heavily, use ArrayList - Arraylist is backed by an Array, so there's no conversion needed. Otherwise a conversion will always need linear time (how could you create a list with different element count in constant time as you need to add a different count).